# Unable to access HTML element from external js in Chrome Extention

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am learning to build Chrome Extensions and am very new to this field. I am working on a very basic extension here and even before I have started on the main task, I am stuck in my demo code. I simply wish to print "hello" or any message in my paragraph tag when I click my extension.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hi</title>
        <style>
        p
        {
            color:red;
            font-size:20px;
        }
        </style>
        <script src="getMSG.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id='content'></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the code for getMSG.js:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Hello';
```

My extentsion was working just fine when I simply wrote "Hello World" in my HTML code. But now when I do this I get no output at all. Please can someone help with this? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the properties of a DOM element you need to do that operation when the window load:

```js
// Using pure JavaScript
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Hello';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I was tested your code and it doesn't work, i think the content page wasn't loaded completely,
So it's preferred to use jQuery accompany this code in your "getMSG.js":

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = 'Hello';
});
```

Works fine for me.

Comment: @DarthCoder: You are welcome! As I don't like raw JavaScript very much, I wondered whether it is possible to use the favorite JavaScript library jQuery in Chrome extensions. It turned out that this is actually very straight-forward. It basically works out-of-the box as you would expect it.